# compare different lists item in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in python

```
listA = [3000, 4000, 5000, 9200, 9800, 11000, 11320]
```

and

```
listB = [3500, 4500, 9500, 9900, 10500, 11191, 11593]
```

Suppose that "n" is the index of all the elements in the two lists I have two check if

```
listA[n] < listB[n-1]
```

and if this is true i must remove these 
two elements.

I am using the code below:

```
for n in range(0, len(listA)):
    if n == 0:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            if listA[n]<listB[n-1]:
                listA.remove(listA[n])
                listB.remove(listB[n-1])
                n = n-1                     
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

from the lists above 9200 and 9800 should be removed as they are smaller than 9500 and 9900. But only the first one is removed. It looks like that in my code n = n-1 has no effect in my loop. Why? How can I get back and check again if elements are removed?

If I print the lists this is what I get:

```
listA = [3000, 4000, 5000, 9800, 11000, 11320]

listB = [3500, 4500, 9900, 10500, 11191, 11593]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python for loop iterates over an iterator, and it each iteration it takes the next element from the iterator.  The position in the iterable is kept as internal state of the iterator and is unrelated to the actual loop variable.  Changing the loop variable inside the loop doesn't have any effect on the next iteration.

You could make your approach work by using `while` insteaf of `if`:

```
for n in range(1, len(listA)):
    try:
        while listA[n] < listB[n-1]:
            listA.pop(n)
            listB.pop(n - 1)
    except IndexError:
        break
```

However, it's best to avoid modifying a list while iterating over it, since that approach is quite error-prone.  Instead, Create new lists including the elements you want to select.

Comment: Yes @Sven Marnach this code is what I need! I thought I would be able to change the loop whenever I want!!

Answer (score 2):

A few things. First, don't modify a list you are iterating over, use an intermediate results list.

Second, you can start from 1 instead of 0.

Also, I'm doing this with append with if not instead of remove, because it was quicker to modify your code for that usecase, but results should be same.

```
start_new = []
end_new = []
try:
    for n in range(1, len(start)):    
        if not start[n]<end[n-1]:
            start_new.append(start[n])
            end_new.append(end[n-1])  
    end_new.append(end[n])                  
except IndexError:
        pass
```

Edit: Moved the try/except, as there is no point in continuing if it already fails with an indexerror.

Comment: @Stifoo your code seems to be working and I understand that changing the loop isn't good idea....but list end_new seems to be missing a value. That is because I am looping over listA and after the last loop the last element if listB isn't read. I suppose i have to manually write it to end_new[] after the indexError raise?

Comment: The original code unconditionally includes the first element of `start` and the last element of `end`, while the code in this answer doesn't.  Moreover, catching `IndexError` seems unnecessary – the implicit assumption is that both lists have the same length.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed! It will be missing the last element? Yes, adding it afterwards would be Fine, I'd say. I'd also move the try/except. Updating code now

Answer (score 1):

You seem to work on lists of increasing values, but I suggest you use `list.pop(index)` instead of `list.remove(list[index])`. The later seems dangerous if the same value may happen twice.

Also, for your issue: you can't update the index afterwards in a `for` loop, since at each iteration, `n` is assigned the next value of the iterator, whatever you might have done to it before (hence, `n = n - 1` has absolutely no effect). If you want to manually change the index value, use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Yes that's right @Arkanosis. I am working with increasing lists. I didn't know that it is a bad idea to change the "n" and in the same time using it to iterate over a list!